# Git commits package as reference

Tags: git, composer-php, phpstorm

I'm creating a module for a legacy app. The deployment doesn't run `composer update` so all the vendor files have to be pushed too.

The problem is (I think) the module I'm creating is on the same git host and the main app, and git thinks that the modules files can just be referenced, but the deployment can not handle it and just creates an empty folder.

PHPStorm shows the commit differences in a very strange way.

[image: Reference icon]

[image: Diff window]

When I push the "files" I only see a sort-of-reference instead of files and folders in gitlab too, unfortunately I don't have a picture of that but it looks like this:
`model-score @a0b1c2d3e4f5`

How can I force git to include the files, and not just a reference?

Comment: One thing to note: you probably want to run `composer install` as part of the deployment, rather than running `composer update`. The former installs dependencies as locked in `composer.lock`, the latter updates them, which might have unexpected effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the package had a `.git` folder in it, and that confused PHPStorm, once deleted everything went back to normal